# fabfile user information requirement

Tags: python, fabric

The remote server is disabling authentication by ssh keys, so when I deploy a new version I need to enter my password (some LDAP authentication).

However, my `fabfile` script will be used by many developers. So, everyone must somehow provide his username to the script.

I thought of this:

```
def authenticate(login=None):
   if login is None:
      abort('You must provide your username')
   ...

@task
def deploy(username=None):
   authenticate(username)
   ...

@task
def init(username=None):
   authenticate(username)
   ...

@task
def rollback(username=None):
   authenticate(username)
   ...

@task
def restart_services(username=None, service=None):
   authenticate(username)
   ...
```

This works fine but not `DRY`.

Is there a clean way to `authenticate` the script user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is DRY you could use a decorator

```
def authenticate(f):
    @functools.wraps(f) 
    def wrapper(login, *args, **kwargs):
       if login is None:
          abort('You must provide your username')
       return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

and then

```
@task
@authenticate
def deploy(whatever):
    ....
```